# Redshift only works on laptop screen, not on external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, redshift

Redshift (v1.12) works fine but only on my laptop's screen, not on the twin external monitors that are what I normally use.  I usually only run the externals, but sometimes run all three together.  But no matter what, the only screen that works is the laptop.

I tried adding "screen=0,1,2" to my .config/redshift.conf file and then ran xrandr and tried "screen=0,DVI-I-1-1,DVI-I-2-2" but that didn't work.

I'm running Lubuntu 20.04LTS, and the twin monitors off a Dell D-3100 docking port...perhaps that has something to do with it?  Anyone out there know what's going on?

Comment: This is aknown issue with redshift: https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/520

Comment: @vanadium Thank you.  Sigh.  Looks like I'm up the creek.  Really appreciate the link to this, as I hadn't found it on my own.  Have a good day.